# Como esconder itens de um menu em C# modelo MVC?

Tags: c#

estou tendo dificuldade em conseguir restringir um acesso de alguns itens do menu da minha aplicação, pois existe um tipo de usuário que terá acesso apenas a determinados itens e o usuário Admin após logar ele terá acesso a todo o conteúdo, ou seja, enquanto não logado o menu ficará escondido exibindo apenas dois itens, se o admin logar ele terá acesso a todo o menu, se o usuário comum logar ele terá acesso apenas há alguns itens do menu. Me mostrem um exemplo de como fazer isso, pois mesmo seguindo a documentação da microsoft eu não consegui fazer essa implementação no meu sistema!

No momento meu problema está nessa linha de código:

```
 public bool IsAdminUser()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = User.Identity;
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
            if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Agora o problema está aqui, não esta buscando o usuário admin!

E aqui é como estou fazendo o menu

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Meu Aplicativo ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="http://www.ebasesistemas.com.br/assets/img/logo.png" title="title" alt="additional title" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                @if (ViewBag.displayMenu == "Yes")
                {
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastros", "Cadastros", "Home")</li><!---adm-->
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatorios", "Relatorios", "Home")</li><!--adm-->
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li><!--apenas logado-->
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li><!--todos-->
                    </ul>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h2>  Seja bem vindo <strong>@ViewBag.Name</strong> :) .Você é um usuário com acesso premium!! </h2>
                }


                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

aqui esta os três models:

```
AccountViewModels

    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PaginaWeb.Models
{
    public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalLoginListViewModel
    {
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class SendCodeViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
        public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerifyCodeViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lembrar deste navegador?")]
        public bool RememberBrowser { get; set; }

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForgotViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lembrar-me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel


    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nome da Empresa")]
        public string nomeEmpresa
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
        public string telefone
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O/A {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar Senha")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a senha de confirmação não correspondem.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O/A {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar senha")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a senha de confirmação não coincidem.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Aqui a IdentityModels:

```
  using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace PaginaWeb.Models
{


    // É possível adicionar dados do perfil do usuário adicionando mais propriedades na sua classe ApplicationUser, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 para obter mais informações.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        public string nomeEmpresa
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string telefone
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Observe que o authenticationType deve corresponder àquele definido em CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Adicionar declarações de usuário personalizado aqui
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui ManageViewModels:

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace PaginaWeb.Models
{
    public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
        public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
        public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManageLoginsViewModel
    {
        public IList<UserLoginInfo> CurrentLogins { get; set; }
        public IList<AuthenticationDescription> OtherLogins { get; set; }
    }

    public class FactorViewModel
    {
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
    }

    public class SetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve ter pelo menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Nova senha")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar nova senha")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "A nova senha e a senha de confirmação não correspondem.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChangePasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Senha atual")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve ter pelo menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Nova senha")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar nova senha")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "A nova senha e a senha de confirmação não correspondem.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddPhoneNumberViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Número de telefone")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerifyPhoneNumberViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Número de telefone")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigureTwoFactorViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
        public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual código você tem no momento?

Comment: Cara já fiz muita coisa, fica até complicado mostrar os códigos aqui

Comment: Tem o código com os itens do MENU creio que você terá que fazer uma verificação nisso.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa consegui resolver o problema da linha de código que coloquei anteriormente, agora o problema está nessa parte ai... Tu não consegue fazer um exemplo disso ai para eu me basear não???? Eu sabia fazer isso usando sitemap, mais visual studio 2017 n permite mais isso!

Comment: Como você está fazendo o MENU, é um PARTIAL VIEW com os links ou você faz no servidor?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e colocar como to fazendo o menu, ele esta na partial view layout!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça 2 métodos assim

```
public bool IsAdmin()
{
        if (!IsAuthenticated())
            return false;

        var user = User.Identity;
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
        if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
            return true;
        return false;
}

public bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Colocar no seu Model,

```
Model.IsAuthenticated = IsAuthenticated();
Model.IsAdmin = IsAdmin();
```

Na sua View

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
    @if(Model.IsAdmin){
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastros", "Cadastros", "Home")</li><!---adm-->
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatorios", "Relatorios", "Home")</li><!--adm-->
    }
    @if(Model.IsAuthenticated){
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li><!--apenas logado-->
    }
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li><!--todos-->
</ul>
```

Comment: Em qual model devo inserir???

Comment: Na model que você retorna com a View, se não tiver crie uma

Comment: Qualquer lugar que eu coloco no model ta dando erro

Comment: Você já usou model alguma vez? cria uma pergunta ou edita essa com o conteúdo do seu controller que eu te mostro como faz

Comment: vou editar agora